# Linear forms which vanish on commutators

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

In some exercise, $E$ denotes the vector space $\mathbb{R}[X]$ and $\mathcal{L}(E)$ the algebra of endomorphisms of $E$. I am asked to determine all the linear forms $T \, : \, \mathcal{L}(E) \, \longrightarrow \, \mathbb{R}$ such that :

$$ \forall u,v \in \mathcal{L}(E), \; T\big( u \circ v \big) = T\big( v \circ u \big). \tag{$\star$} $$

In a previous question, I have shown that there exist $u,v \in \mathcal{L}(E)$ such that $u \circ v - v \circ u = \mathrm{Id}$. As a consequence, I obtain that such a linear form $T$ would satisfy to : $T( \mathrm{Id} ) = 0$. <strike>Moreover, $\mathrm{tr}$ is a linear form defined on $\mathcal{L}(E)$ which satisfies the property $(\star)$ but</strike> I am having trouble finding all of them.

Comment: How do you define the trace for elements of $L(E)$?

Comment: @martini : Yes, you're right. I don't know if that makes sense. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $w \colon E \to E$ be any endomorphism, $u \colon X^i \mapsto X^{i+1}$ the right shift and $v \colon X^{i+1} \mapsto X^i, 1 \mapsto 0$ the left shift. Define $z \colon E \to E$ by 
$$ z(p) = -\sum_{i=0}^\infty u^i \circ w \circ v^{i+1}(p), \quad p\in E $$
note that for any $p \in E$, $z(p)$ is well defined, as $v^{i+1}(p) = 0$ for $i \ge \mathrm{deg}\, p$, that is only finitely many of the summands are non-zero.

We have
\begin{align*}
  u \circ z - z \circ u &= -\sum_i u^{i+1} \circ w \circ v^{i+1} + \sum_i u^i \circ z \circ v^{i} \qquad \text{as $v \circ u = \mathrm{Id}_E$}\\
                        &= u^0 \circ z \circ v^0
\end{align*}
Hence, *any* element $w \in L(E)$ can be written as $w = u\circ z - z \circ u$, that is, any linear form mapping commutators to zero, must map any element to zero: For arbitrary $w$ and $z,u$ as above, we have
$$ T(w) = T(u \circ z - z \circ u) = 0 $$
Hence $T = 0$.